# Touchstart event fires only once

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I'm trying to write a code to change the innerHTML of a single element according to the elements touched by the user. The text has to be taken from the first child of the element touched. After the function is fired once, it doesn't fire anymore.

I wrote this:

```
let title = document.getElementById("title");               //element to be changed
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("elements"); //touchable elements

for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  let ele = elements[i];
  ele.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {
    title.innerHTML = ele.firstChild.innerHTML;
  })
}
```

I wrote an analogous code to work on desktop and, with click events, it works.
Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Could you create a runnable example for us to experience your issue?

Comment: I made this one: it's not the best, but it replies the fundamental structure of the portion of code interested [link] (https://jsfiddle.net/ddavide/jqeanfg2/2/#&togetherjs=Q36h1hvzeC). The problem is that in this runnable example it works as it should! I call the right js file at the bottom of my html file and everything seems ok (as I said, on desktop it works good), but it doesn't work on touch devices. It runs just one time or it doesn't run at all.